# Member fields not initialised in unit tests when set in inspector for unity

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, testing

I have fields that are set in the inspector.
[image]

The length of this array is then printed to the console when the game plays as expected

```
        public void Start() {
            Debug.Log(bootstrapData.Length);
        }

        public void printData()
        {
            Debug.Log(bootstrapData.Length);
        }
```

But when I run a test calling the printData in play mode the bootstrapData is null as they are not set from the inspector I am assuming.

```
[UnityTest]
        public IEnumerator test()
        {
            GameObject go = new GameObject();
            SpriteBootstrap spriteBootstrap = go.AddComponent<SpriteBootstrap>();
            spriteBootstrap.printData(); // null pointer here, data not set

            //... other irrelevant code            
        }
```

Is this normal behaviuor and can I get around this without manualy setting the data in the test.

Comment: Can you load from prefab ??

Comment: One of the elements is null

Comment: Well you do `AddComponent` so it is a **new** component that is not configured via the Inspector yet ...

Comment: @MohammedThaier I'd say OP is rather speaking about `bootstrapData.Length` throwing the exception since `bootstrapData` is `null` .. not an element in it ;)

Comment: @derHugo Yeah that us probably it that makes sense. Is there a way to set this by default when a new component is added like a prefab or something?

Comment: @TimChang Are you saying to load the gameobject with the script from a prefab?

Comment: @JackDelahunt , yes , and that prefab have data already , so you can test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a prefab of the game object and loading it means the fields are set by default.
In this example I am loading a prefab that contains a chunk script, you can then test the chunk script as I was trying to do with the SpriteBootstrap above.

```
GameObject chunkGameObject = MonoBehaviour.Instantiate((Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/Chunk")));
Chunk chunk = firstChunkGameObject.GetComponent<Chunk>();

// you can now use chunk to test
```